# Printing string between pattern using sed

Tags: sed

I have to extract the first parameter of the following function calls using `sed`.

```
strlcpy(p->name,getInfo(NULL,&account)); 
strlcpy(p->balance,getInfo(NULL,&account));
strlcpy(p->number,getInfo(NULL,&account)); 
strlcpy(p->address,getInfo(NULL,&account));
```

Expecting the result of string as below.

```
p->name
p->balance
p->number
p->address
```

Comment: This question has been cross-posted on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46286992/printing-string-between-pattern-using-sed)

Answer (score 1):

I would use `awk` for this rather than a `sed` substitution:

```
$ awk -F '[(,]' '{ print $2 }' file
p->name
p->balance
p->number
p->address
```

It sees each line as a number of fields separated by either `(` or `,`, and prints the second field.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/[^(]*(\([^,]*\),.*/\1/' input.txt
```

**Input**

```
strlcpy(p->name,getInfo(NULL,&account)); 
strlcpy(p->balance,getInfo(NULL,&account));
strlcpy(p->number,getInfo(NULL,&account)); 
strlcpy(p->address,getInfo(NULL,&account));
```

**Output**

```
p->name
p->balance
p->number
p->address
```